# ViewController's background color is not changing in viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift

If i assign VC's bg color as any color from iPhoneSdk in storyboard then below code works fine but if i assign VC's bg color any color from NamedColor then below code does not work

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Comment: Try `UIColor.red`.

Comment: some other view is covering your view ... please verify ...

Comment: A little clarification is needed... *"below code does not work"* -- what does that mean? The code you show is `self.view.backgroundColor = .red` ... does that ***not*** change the background to red? Or do you mean, yes, that ***does*** change it to red, but using something like `self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "MyRed")` doesn't?

Comment: @DonMag in both cases it does not work if i set my view's colors from asset's colors in storyboard

Comment: @EmmaAlden - what do you get in the Debug Console if you put this line in there `print(UIColor(named: "MyBlue"))` (obviously, replace "MyBlue" with your color name)?

Comment: @DonMag Normally both 'self.view.backgroundColor = .red' or 'self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "MyBlue")' work if in storybord I initialize vc's colors from system colors...

Comment: @EmmaAlden - sorry, you are not making sense... what do you get in the Debug Console with `print(UIColor(named: "MyBlue"))`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `viewWillAppear()` for interface configuration:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.view.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Comment: No it does not change. I edited my question. The problem with NamedColor's colors i guess

Comment: @EmmaAlden Were you able to get a solution for this issue? I am also facing the same with one of my projects

Answer (score 0):

I just test it again and it works just fine to set the colour of a `Viewcontroller's` view in `viewDidLoad`.
what i experience is, I had a view inside the `contentView` that took up most of the visible area, so very little of my `customColor` was visible. I had to set the background color of my subview to clear before I could see the changed background color.

Is it possible that you have a subview that completely fills your content view and hiding it's `backgroundColor`?

If that's not the case, try adding a `breakpoint` to your `viewDidLoad` method to make sure it's being called.

Comment: I guess the problem with asset's colors. If in storyboard i assign any color that i created then it does not work

Comment: what do you mean by assets colors ?

Comment: @jawadAli It's new in iOS 11, where you can set custom colors in storyboard as assets isntead of "custom color"